# Best Arduino for Midi-Board

Tags: arduino, midi

I came across this device recently: The [Loupedeck](https://loupedeck.com/). Now, most reviews say that it's built very poorly and a simple Midi controller paired with [Midi2LR](http://midi2lightroom.com/index.php/en/) will get the job done better and cheaper.

But, I've now got it in my head that it would be a fun project build my own Midi board. So, I'm looking at the right Arduino for the project. (This is my first foray into this type of thing, hence the very basic question...)

The [Uno](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-uno-rev3) seems to be exactly what I need, except for the limitation of 6 analogue inputs. The Loupedeck has 57 buttons - and with possible expand-ability in mind...it seems like having the ability to support ~75 input devices would be good.

So, here's my conundrum - **do I need to find an Arduino that can support that many analogue devices, or will using the digital inputs be okay? Is there a best practice for whether or not to use analogue vs. digital inputs?**

Thanks,

Comment: Digital inputs should be fine for most controls.

Answer (score -3):

If you have not done product design many times before, you will learn it is not that easy to do as good a job as they did .

One [reviewer](https://www.macworld.com/article/3252816/input-devices/loupedeck-review-puts-adobe-lightroom-classic-ccs-controls-at-your-fingertips.html) said "*The Loupedeck’s build quality is very good; nothing feels loose or cheap.*" 
[image]

You might be able to improve it starting with the unit , but it does not look poorly designed on the outside. But may need care from abuse.

Maybe you really want this.
[image]

I realize everything that was asked, but sometimes people have no clue what it takes for the expected high class design requested. It is not trivial even for EE grad's with 10 yrs experience. It comes from working on the job with the best experts.

The best answer comes from decades of practical experience. But if you have none, this is over-ambitious for a 1st time.  Start with a plan. Digital is always bettern than analog because of the reliability aspect and incremental digital volume controls are exclusively used now, instead of pots in high quality equipment ( cars , DSO's etc.) The question indicates no experience which even the best in this forum would have a hard time doing everything , electrical, mechanical,  polymer overlay, EMI, tactile feel, an ergonomic 1st class  HMI etc required and make it "better" than this example.  If you know nothing about integration design , EMI and ESD proof, you have a long road to haul without mentors on the job.

Frankly it's hard to do it better. But if you want to learn start with an Arduino and their Mickey Mouse Shields or an RPi and shop for digital peripherals and learn to integrate 100 analog and/or digital I/O's in real time.

But start with a good "spec" and a better plan. Have fun.

Comment: The OP wasn't asking for MIDI controller recommendations.

Comment: @duskwuff is right. While I can appreciate your input, and that I may in fact be getting in over my head, I am very much looking to pair this with my recent woodworking hobby and build my own. Part of the thrill of new hobbies is in the experimentation and learning. I'm here asking for the advice that will jump start this project for me. Also - 1 review said it was good. The vast majority say it's overpriced for the quality and that the buttons feel cheap. That's a side note though. I'm here because I came to the conclusion that I'd like to build my own.

Comment: I knew that (-1) have fun. A little is an understatement.  and some may find their expertise cheapened by comparison.

Comment: I don't understand how me doing this project cheapens anyone else's expertise. I used to be a pro photographer - someone building their own camera doesn't cheapon cameras or pros. In fact, the whole pinhole genre of the art is comprised almost entirely of DIY cameras. Likewise, me building my own midi board doesn't take away from anyone else.

Comment: Your edit gives me some useful advice to get moving. So, have a +1 - it's on the house.

Comment: sincere comments mean more to me than points.  Don't go too  simple when these are cheap https://www.geeky-gadgets.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/UDOO-X86-Mini-PC.jpg with 12V 3A

Comment: @TonyStewartEEsince1975 - I've got a plan worked up to build the box out of oak, utilize the Mega2560 Arduino + HIDUINO + Midi2LR. I'll send you a picture when it's done so that expertise's don't feel cheapened :-)

Comment: I don't really feel cheapened unless it's made from zebra wood, j/k it's just that naive questions often underestimate the task of Mastering everything well. Just ask Tiger Woods, so to say you want to improve on a professional product with no experience, falls in that category.  You could get a couple 48 I/O "yoyo" chips and reduce the size of your box. It's like saying you can master woodworking so maybe I can beat Tiger Woods on the gold err, golf course.